# how can I monitor (listen) the job I scheduled with @scheduled using spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, monitoring

I needed to schedule a job which should run indefinitely. I found this nice article (although it has spring3 example) and followed through.

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-3-task-scheduling-via.html

While this is a good starting point, i wasn't able to find how i can monitor the status of the job running. I'd like to know if there's a way for me to monitor scheduled jobs so i can be notified if something went wrong and jobs just died (such as job threw exception and exited).

Answer (score 0):

@Scheduled is a shortcut that uses a bunch of defaults including the Queue.  I believe it's an ExecutorService so if you just @Autowire that, you can interrogate it for status.

For more control (like how to handle jobs that throw exceptions) you can create a bean that's your own ExecutorService and put it in the context.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i guess what you're saying is executor that is executing the tasks has method(s) that returns the status of jobs? also could you be little more specific on your 2nd approach?

Comment: what do you mean by interrogate it for status? Would you do that in a separate job? Where would that information get posted?

Comment: ExecutorService is an interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Depending on what spring is doing behind the scenes, you'll get some implementation of that.  The implementation might have methods for checking the status of job.